# Can't access Gnome extension - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, lts, gnome-shell-extension, extension

I can't access the extensions manager in-app, no result found or the site, site can't be reached. I'm new to `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`

Any solution?

Comment: Are you able to access https://extensions.gnome.org in a web browser? (It looks like the site is down at the moment???)

Comment: No, I tried to open the site, but it says "site can't reach". I also tried to open the site on my phone, cant reach too.

Comment: I just checked gnome.org on https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/gnome.org.html, and it says "Gnome.org is DOWN for everyone. It is not just you. The server is not responding..." So this is probably the cause of your issue.

Comment: got it, thank you